# What's the problem here?

Tags: help, connection

```
6/28/19, 21:53:13.840 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
6/28/19, 21:53:13.844 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
6/28/19, 21:53:15.260 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection
6/28/19, 21:53:15.517 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
6/28/19, 21:53:34.859 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 103.196.181.217:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")
```

Comment: You did not provide enough information to say. Are you at a location that may block Tor? (example: University, Work, Hotel) Are you in a country the may block Tor? Are you seeing the same outcome using a bridge?

Answer (score 1):

That log shows that Tor couldn't connect to one of the Proxy clients. If that's the last message that you got, then the issue is pretty *minor*. One of the many proxies are unavailable.

Simply try to connect again.

If you're behind a filtered network, try rotating bridges by clicking on the button that says "Configure Tor", and choosing a bridge from the list. Then try to connect.